# How do you make a rails engine do eager loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading, rails-engines

I have a rails 4 **engine** called `the_great_library`, where I have a hard time getting it to eager load files correctly.

In the engine I have a file located in `/lib/the_great_library` called `book_lookup_service.rb`. Now the file contains something like this:

```
class NoBookMatchingTitle < StandardError;end
module TheGreatLibrary
  class BookLookupService

    def self.find_book name
      if book = Book.find_by_name(name)
        return book
      else
        raise NoBookMatchingTitle.new("The book named #{name} could not be found!")
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Now my problem is, that if I start the rails console from the dummy app like so `cd spec/dummy & rails c` and type: `NoBookMatchingTitle.new` I get: `NameError: uninitialized constant NoBookMatchingTitle`

How do I solve this?

**Note:**
I have tried to put `config.eager_load_paths += "#{config.root}/lib"` in `engine.rb`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Found this through Google, did you ever find a solution to this?